# TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named model.urls

Tags: django, django-templates

Template error -

```
Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named model.urls
21      <!-- Header -->
22      <div id="header">
23          <div id="branding">
24          {% block branding %}{% endblock %}
25          </div>
26          {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
27          <div id="user-tools">
28              {% trans 'Welcome,' %}
29              <strong>{% filter force_escape %}{% firstof user.first_name user.username %}{% endfilter %}</strong>.
30              {% block userlinks %}
31                  {% url django-admindocs-docroot as docsroot %}
32                  {% if docsroot %}
33                      <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
34                  {% endif %}
35                  {% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}
36                  {% if password_change_url %}
37                      <a href="{{ password_change_url }}">
38                  {% else %}
39                      <a href="{{ root_path }}password_change/">
40                  {% endif %}
41                  {% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
```

What could be the problem?

**The Answer [Edit] -**
If you get an error like this (I mean this un-django) then its probably a mis-type somewhere in your code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, somewhere in your project you are importing `model.urls`, which is a very un-django place to put something related to `urls` and makes me think you just mis-typed a line. There are no `urls` inside of a `models` folder or `models` file in the django project.

While that specific error @ admin-docs is notorious for giving a useless traceback (the real error is too deep), can you post it anyways?

Either way, I would search your own source code for `model.urls` via grep to fix your problem.
Navigate to your project root folder and type in `grep -r "model.urls" .`

Comment: Hey, you would know if this applies to you or not! Do you have a folder called `model` where you might be storing a `urls`? That was just my guess that it's a mis-type. I'm also assuming this isn't pesudo code, and the error actually says `model.urls`. If you'd like further help, post the traceback and your urls.py

Comment: Instead of typing "ec_model.urls" i typed "model.urls" ..... sometimes   the only thing between you and changing the world are some stupid mistakes ...: P